Why is the vector making equal angle with 3 non zero non-coplanar vectors [a,b&c] is not along Σa[unit vector]
So the vector is along is Σ (a[unit vector] × b [unit vector])
Which can be derived by common plane intesection of both equiangular plane to both the vectors but
Intuitively it feels it should be along Σ unit vectors, is there any proof why does it fail

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
